# MS-Access Query to Generate Integers say 1 to 1000

Tags: sql, ms-access

Sir I want to generate a series of integers say (from 1 to 1000) using query statement. BUT i do not want to use any Table nor want to create any Table.

I know this is possible in SQL Server but show the similar query for MS-Access 2003 too.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe cannot be done in a single Access SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

It you do not want to create a table. Then in Access I only think that you have this option left:

```
Select 1
Union All Select 2
Union All Select 3
Union All Select 4
Union All Select 5
Union All Select 6
Union All Select 7
Union All Select 8
Union All Select 9
Union All Select 10
Union All Select 11
--And so on
```

Comment: Could u not use a loop to perform it?

Comment: You could do a loop yes. But where do you want to store the values between the iterations?